# How to extend a Magento 1.9 model source [Solved]

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I need to remove an option from original options so I extended the core model. The original file looks like this:

> app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Source/Import/Behavior.php

```php
class Mage_ImportExport_Model_Source_Import_Behavior
{
    /**
     * Prepare and return array of import behavior.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array(
                'value' => Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND,
                'label' => Mage::helper('importexport')->__('Append Complex Data')
            ),
            array(
                'value' => Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE,
                'label' => Mage::helper('importexport')->__('Replace Existing Complex Data')
            ),
            array(
                'value' => Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import::BEHAVIOR_DELETE,
                'label' => Mage::helper('importexport')->__('Delete Entities')
            )
        );
    }
}
```

I have an extension that is used to extend all core files and the extended file below. This **My_CoreExtension** extension is already enabled and extending a few other core files and they are all working fine.

The problem is that my extended *Bahavior.php* is not called so I know my extend way is not rigtht but I don't know how to fix it.

> app/code/local/My/CoreExtension/Model/ImportExport/Source/Import/Behavior.php

```php
class My_CoreExtension_Model_ImportExport_Source_Import_Behavior extends Mage_ImportExport_Model_Source_Import_Behavior
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array(
                'value' => Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND,
                'label' => Mage::helper('importexport')->__('Append Complex Data')
            ),
            array(
                'value' => Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE,
                'label' => Mage::helper('importexport')->__('Replace Existing Complex Data')
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the *config.xml* and I've removed unrelated parts.

> app/code/local/My/CoreExtension/etc/config.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_CoreExtension>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </My_CoreExtension>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <importexport>
                <rewrite>
                    <import_source_behavior>My_CoreExtension_Model_ImportExport_Source_Import_Behavior</import_source_behavior>
                </rewrite>
            </importexport>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue myself.
`<import_source_behavior>` is not only for naming but also tells Magento where to locate the file to replace. According to the original file at `app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Source/Import/Behavior.php`, the naming should be changed to `<source_import_behavior>`.